# react-hook-form useFieldArray append validation based on the previous array eleement

Tags: react-hook-form

In react-hook-form for dynamic fields we use useFieldArray. When we add a new field it does not check whether the previous array element input fields are valid or not.

I want to have a functionality where it will check the previous array element fields are valid or not. If they are valid then it will let append a new array element, otherwise it will show error message to the specific index field of the array.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "trigger" provided by react-hook-form

Need to declare this constant first.

```
const {trigger} = useFormContext();
```

Then add this function to your add button to check validation, it's up to you if you want to check other fields.

```
const checkValidate = await trigger(["yourFieldName"])
if(checkValidate === true) {
   append()
}
```